# Scrapy: Unable to find form button

Tags: javascript, python, html, asp.net, scrapy

I'm trying to login to a web site using scrapy and it is unable to find the correct submit button as there is a search button and the login button. I'm aware that in these cases I need to use clickdata but I am unable to get scrapy to locate the button that needs to be clicked.

The website I'm trying to scrap is formatted poorly so I'm unable to simply use a  name or ID to locate the button. The only way I can identify the button in the code is via the class, which i'm not even sure if it is unique. For whatever reason even with the class I scrapy is unable to locate the button.

If it helps the website is in ASP and I think the button runs a javascript.

Button HTML

```
<tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button tabindex="0" class="x-btn-text" type="button" style="position: relative; width: 64px; height: 15px;">Login</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr>
```

Scrapy login code

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = {loginInputName: login, passwordInputName: password}, clickdata = {'class': 'x-btn-text'}, callback = self.check_login_response(response))
```

Comment: Please note that ``FormRequest.from_response`` looks for a ``form`` to submit, it doesn't actually simulate the click of a button (at least, not in the same sense that a browser automation tool would do it). Is there even a form for this button? If the button click is handled only via JavaScript only, ``from_response`` won't help here: you'll have to inspect the network tab of your browser developer tools to see what request it's being made and then recreate it using FormRequest in your spider's code.

Comment: The form only exists for the fields not the buttons.
Thanks this should give me enough info to work it out.

I would mark this as answered but I can't find the button.

Comment: oh, lemme post this as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that [`FormRequest.from_response`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) looks for a form to submit, it doesn't actually simulate the click of a button (at least, not in the same sense that a browser automation tool would do it).

Is there even a form for this button?

If the button click is handled only via JavaScript only, `from_response` won't help here: you'll have to inspect the network tab of your browser developer tools to see what request it's being made and then recreate it using `FormRequest(url, formdata=params)` in your spider's code.